# How get `attribute1' from ComponentB in React?

Tags: reactjs

JSX:

```
<ComponentA attr="attribute1">
  Text inside ComponentA. <ComponentB>Text inside ComponentB</ComponentB>. 
</ComponentA>
```

In React, how get 'attribute1' inside ComponentA from ComponentB?

Comment: I think the JSX you've pasted does not illustrate your point: In the code above component A gets `"attribute1"`via `props.attr`. If you want to pass that down to `ComponentB` simply pass it as props. `<ComponentB attr={props.attr}>...` in the render method of `ComponentA`

Comment: @Taxel I think that can get `"attribute1"` if `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` is include to same parent component or `ComponentA` is parent of `ComponentB`. But I assume that `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` is different component that isn't parent-child relationship, I want to know how to get 'attribute1' in `ComponentA` with `ComponentB` in this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to pass down a function that can update a shared variable from the parent class or look into using state management such as Redux - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux